# How do I create a javascript function with a parameter that may be undefined?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have found similar questions about creating functions with optional parameters. But I continually run into errors is the parameter may not exist. I have an interactive map that is doing a bunch of things. However if outputlayer is null, the function will not execute. This layer may or may not exist. I just can't seem to figure out how to pass this optional parameter in if it doesn't exist. Thanks for any help!

```
function appdelete(selected,vectorlayer,drawFeature,outputlayer) {

    $(selected).prev().children().children().eq(2).val('Latitude');
    $(selected).prev().children().children().eq(4).val('Longitude');
    vectorlayer.destroyFeatures();
    drawFeature.activate();

    try {
        map.removeLayer(outputlayer);
    } catch(err) { };
}
```

Comment: Why don't just check `if(outputlayer === undefined) return;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if it exists first and maybe the type.

```
if(outputlayer && "object" === typeof outputlayer) {
    map.removeLayer(outputlayer);
}
```

Comment: I actually misstated something. When output layer doesn't exist, the function will not even begin to execute. I get an error:Uncaught ReferenceError: sllayer is not defined

Comment: When the function executes, that is the layer which is passed through the outputlayer parameter. I am calling this function through jQuery:    '$("#sightlinedelete").click( function(){appdelete($(this),slvectorLayer,sldrawFeature,sllayer)})'

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code. If sllayer isn't defined then that variable doesn't exist when you make that call.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check if the variable exists:

```
if(outputlayer){
    map.removeLayer(outputlayer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only care `undefined`, do this:

```
if(outputlayer === undefined) return;
```

or

```
if(outputlayer !== undefined) {
    map.removeLayer(outputlayer);
}
```

Comment: Leave out the "undefined" check, so you won't `removeLayer` on a `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter initialyzing:

```
outputlayer= (typeof outputlayer=== "undefined") ? "someDefaultValue" : outputlayer;
```

In your function:

```
function appdelete(selected,vectorlayer,drawFeature,outputlayer) {
    outputlayer= (typeof outputlayer=== "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : outputlayer;
    $(selected).prev().children().children().eq(2).val('Latitude');
    $(selected).prev().children().children().eq(4).val('Longitude');
    vectorlayer.destroyFeatures();
    drawFeature.activate();

    map.removeLayer(outputlayer);    
}
```